# Hibernate Mapping of nested collection in java to mapping table through java annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, annotations, mapping

I am facing difficulty to write hibernate mapping with java annotation for problem as given below.

Problem:

**Tables**

```
Table:Courses_Teachers
columns:
id
course_id
teacher_id
year(academic year)
```

```
Table: Courses_Students
columns:
id
course_id
student_id
year(academic year)
```

```
Table: Courses_Teachers_Students
course_teacher_id
course_student_id
```

**Classes**

```
class Student {
    Map<Course,List<Teacher>> courseTeachersMap;  
}
```

**Requirements**

- A course can be taught by multiple teachers to same student group .
- A course is assigned to a grade level.
- A grade level can have multiple student groups who are assigned different set of teachers for a course.

Please suggest me how to specify annotation for courseTeachersMap property in class student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to map a `ManyToMany` association using a `Map`, and a typicall use case for this kind of mapping is when you have a ternary association. For example, if you have:

```
STUDENT_TEACHER_COURSE
STUDENT_ID(FK, PK)
TEACHER_ID(FK, PK)
COURSE_ID (FK, PK)
```

Then you could define the following mapping (assuming you're using a Hibernate Annotations < 3.5):

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="STUDENT_TEACHER_COURSE", 
        joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID") }
    )
    @MapKeyManyToMany(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID",unique = false))
    protected Map<Course,Teacher> teachers ;
    ...
}
```

But **I don't think you can have a "nested" `List<Teacher>` as value inside the `Map`**, I don't think Hibernate can map that and I'd consider getting the `List` from an entity instead.

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations 3.4 Reference Guide

  - [2.4.6.2.2. Map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-map)
- Hibernate Annotations 3.5 Reference Guide

  - [2.2.5.3.4. Indexed collections (List, Map)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-collections-overview)

#### Resources

- [@MapKeyManyToMany and value column name](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=974839)
- [Help with annotations -- Map](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=956662)

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. Do you see/know any better approach? What the OP wants looks very exotic to me.

Comment: Your solution sounds good. But if he want an exotic mapping, he should use a lot of wrappers @Embeddable classes. I hope he provide some information about your approach.

Comment: When i said *A lot of relationships* i refer to the mapping provided by @Maddy.Shik :)

Comment: Thanks for solution. As u suggested approach i am following is little exotic and nested collection is also not possible with hibernate. You mentioned to use Entity instead of list, that is possible only if i use Class corresponding to mapping table which doesn't seem in accordance with coding principles. Can u please suggest your approach?

Comment: Java Map will not allow non unique key. So only one course-teacher pair can be retrieved which will not fit my requirement.